# Difference between firebaseio.com & firebaseio-demo.com

Tags: firebase

I'm just getting started with my Firebase account and I'm reading through the documentation. What is the difference between and app's firebaseio.com & firebaseio-demo.com urls? Is one production and one development?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firebase employee here.

The difference is only for us internally. It's mostly for documentation and other demo purposes.

The demo urls are world-writable instances for tutorials and examples. They are not guaranteed and could disappear at any time
they can't have security rules or enforce authentication. firebaseio.com urls are the real deal, production ready, fully functional, and won't be cleared out the next time we do maintenance on the demo server.

To have development version of Firebase you just need to create one as you usually would and populate it with your dev data.

#### tl;dr - It's internal. Other firebases don't get demo instances. Don't worry about it.